# Nginx can't find user directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

i'm having trouble configure my server on nginx, i'm tryng to deploy a RoR applicaion with passenger when i try to start nginx i recive this error:

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "icaro" in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:125
```

here is my server configuration on the nginx.conf

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
    passenger_enabled on;
    location / {
        icaro /icarodroplet/public;
    }
}
```

if i change the icaro (my deployment user) to root i won't recive this error, but server cant find my application directory.

what i'm doing wrong? this give me headches D:

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think root means the root user here. It means the root directory for the project. You can change the user at the top of the conf file. There might be something like `user  nobody;` Change it to your user. [Here is a good link to follow](http://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2013/07/19/centos-6-4-server-setup-with-ruby-on-rails-nginx-and-postgresql/).

```
server { 
  listen 80;
  server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
  passenger_enabled on;
  location / {
    root /icarodroplet/public;
  }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOUUU, omg i cant belive is that obvious, i'm a just beginner and i'm doing so many things that's new to me, and something like that i can't get.